# Batch file cannot find the extension file specified in the script

Tags: windows

I have a batch file that detects csv files and moves them to another folder.

But since sometimes now the script does not work anymore and it was working totally fine before.

Is there any clue why these files are not detected anymore?

I have checked the script and it seems totally fine.

Script below:

```
@echo off 
set LOGFILE="D:\M\logs\runquery.log"
cd D:\M\output
if exist *.csv 
    ( move *.csv D:\M\output\archive >> %LOGFILE% cd D:\M\bin ) 
else 
    ( echo "No file was generated" >> %LOGFILE% cd D:\M\bin )
```

thank you.

Regards,

Comment: Please paste your code or it's impossible to give any feedback

Comment: Code is below :@echo off

set LOGFILE="D:\M\logs\runquery.log"

cd D:\M\output

if exist *.csv (
 move *.csv D:\M\output\archive >> %LOGFILE% 
 cd D:\M\bin
) else (
 echo "No file was generated" >> %LOGFILE%
 cd D:\M\bin
)

Answer (score 0):

I tried the code on my PC, it works. Did you try to launch it from `cmd`? Do you see any warning / error?
You pasted the code in the comments, so I have no idea of the indentation, but be careful with the parenthesis, they have to be put exactly like this:

```
@echo off 
set LOGFILE="D:\M\logs\runquery.log"
cd D:\M\output
if exist *.csv ( 
    move *.csv D:\M\output\archive >> %LOGFILE%
    cd D:\M\bin
) else ( 
    echo "No file was generated" >> %LOGFILE%
    cd D:\M\bin
)
```

otherwise the script will give an error: "The syntax of the command is incorrect".

Also check your folder tree, if any of the folders (M, logs, output, archive, bin) doesn't exist, the script will fail.

Comment: Hi,thanks your answer.actualy we dont get any error we receive the message no file was generated even if there is a csv file in the folder.all the folder does excist and the script was working before

Comment: Have you tried launching the script as administrator? Maybe some permissions have changed?